# How to handle app redirects to browser in appium?

Tags: android, redirect, browser, appium

I am stuck in step in my test that application redirects to browser page for the payment. After the payment page opened it says:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I know that the id of the element is correct. I can't switch to the browser as far as I understand.
Appium gives error when I tried to use `driver.switch_to.window();` does not work on appium  I guess. (as far as for android on windows I suppose. It says its not implemented yet)
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here ,Application Under Test can be termed as *Hybrid Application* where, the business logic of application is handled with `Web services`. In this case, *processing the payment*.

You are approaching to it quite correctly by allowing driver to *switch* to something. Only in case of mobile application automation, we have below method (assuming you are using appium with Java):

```
public void appTest() throws InterruptedException{

            Set<String> text = ((AndroidDriver) driver).getContextHandles();
              System.out.println(text);   
             for (String contexts : text) {
              if (contexts.contains("WEBVIEW_com.hk8securities.app8now"))
              {
             ((AndroidDriver) driver).context(contexts);
              System.out.println(contexts);
              }
              else{
                  System.out.println("not switched");
              }
             }
  }
```

For understanding available contexts, print them first on console and then switch to it. 
As per my observation, in android it returns *NATIVE_APP*,*WEBVIEW_WEBVIEWNAME*. In iPhone, it do not provide name for webview/s but only WEBVIEW_1/2/3 and so on. Also these numbers keep changing the number of times you run your tests.

Hope this will help to get you started.

Comment: It stucks when it finds first context includes WEBVIEW after a few seconds test crashes. I can't manage it but thanks anyway.